# file name is undefined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Right this is what I want for the solution. When the user clicks on the "Cancel" button, it would try to find the file name of the file that is going to be cancelled and then delete the database row containing that file name.

The problem is that it is not recognizing the file name as it is stating that `imagecancelname=undefined`. As this is undefined, it can't delete the database row containing the file name as it doesn't recognize the name of the file. By doing a print $imagecancelsql it is displaying this below after I have cancelled uploading a file:

```
DELETE FROM Image WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/undefined'
```

So the question is that how can I get `imagecancelname` to recognise the name of the file which is going to be cancelled so then it can be used to be able to delete the database row containing the file name?

Below is the current form code:

```
var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return startImageUpload(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
  "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
  "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" +     
  "</p><p class='imagef1_cancel' align='center'></p>" +
  "<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

Below is the startImageUpload function where it displays the cancel button when file is uploading and where it contains the cancel button function if the user clicks on the Cancel button:

```
    var sourceImageForm; 

         function startImageUpload(imageuploadform, imagecancelname){

  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','visible');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','visible');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','hidden');
  sourceImageForm = imageuploadform;

/*The above would show and hide elements within the form the file is being uploaded.
For example if I have three forms and the second form is uploading a file, then it
shows and hides the elements within the second form only */

        $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_cancel').html('<div><button type="button" class="imageCancel" id="image_cancel_' + imagecancelname + '">Cancel</button></div>').find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
        $.ajax("cancelimage.php?imagecancelname=" + $(this).attr('id').slice(13));

});       
      return true;
}
```

Finally below is the cancelimage.php script where when the user clicks on the Cancel button, it will navigate to this script and this is where the script is used to delete the database row by finding the file name using the $GET method.

```
<?php

  // ... connected to DB

  $image_cancel_ = $_GET["imagecancelname"];
  $imagecancelsql = "
    DELETE FROM Image 
    WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($image_cancel_)."'
  ";

  print $imagecancelsql;

  mysql_close();

?>
```

Below is the print of the query:

Notice: Undefined index: imagecancelname in /web/stud/xxx/Mobile_app/cancelimage.php on line 19
array(0) { } DELETE FROM Image WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/'

Comment: not sure if it will help, but shouldn't it be `<input type="button"... />` instead of `<button type="button"...></button>` ?

Comment: @jbabey I just looked at w3schools, it is definetly `<button></button>`

Comment: @user1391585 http://w3fools.com/ - although in this isntance they are correct.

Comment: @user1391585 ...which my spelling is not. Instance. Obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the browser does not like the custom attribute you defined on the button to hold the file path. However, you can easily store this information in a standard attribute - the `id`. Try this JS instead:

```
function startImageUpload(imagecancelname){
  // All this can be chained into one since .html() returns the correct jQuery object
  $('.imagef1_cancel').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).html('<div><button type="button" class="imageCancel" id="image_cancel_' + imagecancelname + '">Cancel</button></div>').find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
    $.ajax("cancelimage.php?imagecancelname=" + $(this).attr('id').slice(13));
  });     
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Before I test this, what does slice(13) mean?

Comment: It's basically the same as the PHP `substr()` function. Here, it's cutting the first 13 characters off the ID before sending it to the server, because I added the 13 characters `image_cancel_` to the beginning of the ID to help avoid collisions with other IDs you may already have on your page.  [See this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: It is giving me an error in error console: $(this).attr('id') is undefined. Update code in question

Comment: You seem to have leaked a space in there instead of an underscore - yours is `image_cancel ' + imagecancelname`, mine is `image_cancel_' + imagecancelname`

Comment: Also your function now makes no sense, please try substituting your entire function code for the code above, I have wrapped the two `$('.imagef1_cancel').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex)...` lines into a single statement.

Comment: I have changed the code and it has fixed the error. But still when I click on the cancel button, it does not delete the database row which has just been inserted. Do I need to change $image_cancel to $image_cancel_ in php script (cancelimage.php)? Shall I show you php script of file upload because in there you will see that when file is uploaded, then it inserts a row. It would be great though that it recognizes that if user was uploading a file and then cancelled it, that it would not insert a row at all. Code updated in question.

Comment: Are you still getting `undefined` in your query? What does the query you build now look like?

Comment: Hi Dave, Sorry for getting back to you late, I have update php script to show what the query looks like and I have also printed the query which you can see above :)

Comment: Well I don;t get why that would happen, can you show `var_dump($_GET);` in the PHP script?

Comment: Hi, sorry there is maintence work where I live in selby so power will be on and off all day so I wasn't able to connect to internet till power came back on. Anyway I opened up both the application and the php script (cancelimage.php). I uploaded the a file in the application and then refreshed the cancelimage.php page and updated in the question it now shows what the var_dump($GET) and print query shows. It is showing nothing in the array

Comment: I've just spotted a couple of problems - 1) Your HTML in the for the form is invalid, it has a closing `</p>` with no open tag and a closing `</label>` with no opening tag 2) You are passing the form *element* to the `startImageUpload()` function, and attempting to store it as a string in the HTML you add to the `imagef1_cancel` element. This will not work. You need to give each form a unique `id`, and use this string to identify the upload that needs to be cancelled. I don't have time to write a full demo now but I will try and do a working example for you after work - have a go yourself now.

Comment: The `<p>` and `</label>` were just typing errors when I was putting this code in SO, I was trying to minimise the form code as much as I can and I forgot to delete the label tag, but in the application those tags are opened properly. But I will have a go myself and see if I can sort it out before your working example. Thanks :)

Comment: I still havn't got it working but still giving it a go. I have updated startImageUpload() function so you can see whole code to see what is happening. I attempted to change `('.imagef1_cancel')...` to `$(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_cancel')...` in function but still not deleting the row off the database and still states nothing in the array within the var_dump($GET)

Comment: @user1391585 Sorry I didn't get back to you last night, ended up stuck in the office til about 9PM. Glad you got it working :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the image should not be stored in your DB before the complete upload. If the image is cancelled, then it will not be in DB.

To answer the precise question of undefined, in jquery, attr is to get markup attribute. (  ).

You should put an id on your file upload input :

```
<input id='fileImage' name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' />
```

and then use it to get the value

```
var image_cancel = $('#fileImage').val();
```

Comment: When you said image should not be in db before upload is complete, that is actually what I wanted to do but I didn't know how to do this. The problem is that while file is uploading, it inserts the db row, when I press cancel, because file was in its uploading process, then it inserted row in database. Anyway can I show you php script of file upload so you can see when database row is inserted?

Comment: I can't use the file input textbox to retreive the file name. Reason for this is that if I upload "Tulips.png" for first time, in server it saves it as "Tulips.png", but if I upload same file second time, then in server it saves it as "Tulips_2.png". This is in php script where it uploads the file

Comment: in the php upload script, there is a move_uploaded_file() function. If this function is successfull, the you update your DB row with your copied file.